# How do I create a Bubble Sort in Perl

Tags: perl, sorting

I am trying to create a simple bubble sort in Perl but it doesn't seem to work. Can any one help me?

Code:

```
for ( my $i = 1; $i < @array; $i++ ) {

    for ( my $k = 0; $k = @array < $i - 1; $k++ ) {

        if ( $array[$k] > $array[ $k + 1 ] ) {
            $temp            = $array[$k];
            $array[$k]       = $array[ $k + 1 ];
            $array[ $k + 1 ] = $temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Then when I iterate through the array again it is not sorted.

Comment: Please note that the chosen answer to this question is incorrect.

Comment: So note, the code in OP is incorrect.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the inner `for` loop's *while* clause `$k = @array < $i - 1` but it's not right! You're assigning to `$k` the boolean result of comparing the size of `@array` with `$i - 1`. An assignment in that clause is very unusual, but also that value will always be *false*, represented as the empty string, so your loop will never be executed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should avoid this sort of confusion by using list version of `for`

```
my @array = ( 5, 6, 3, 1, 7, 3, 2, 9, 10, 4 );

for my $i ( 1 .. $#array ) {
    for my $k ( 0 .. $i - 1 ) {
        @array[ $k, $k + 1 ] = @array[ $k + 1, $k ]
            if $array[$k] > $array[ $k + 1 ];
    }
}

print "@array\n";
```

You can prevent a lot of bugs in this way and code is more readable because there is clearly visible intent what do you like to achieve. Which leads to the realisation your algorithm is wrong and what you would probably like is

```
my @array = ( 5, 6, 3, 1, 7, 3, 2, 9, 10, 4 );

for my $i ( reverse 1 .. $#array ) {
    for my $k ( 0 .. $i - 1 ) {
        @array[ $k, $k + 1 ] = @array[ $k + 1, $k ]
            if $array[$k] > $array[ $k + 1 ];
    }
}

print "@array\n";
```

Comment: @sebnukem If it doesn't work and it was copied from your answer, that would suggest that your answer doesn't work either ;) Regardless, I don't see how you can claim plagiarism here: this answer moves from the front of the array to the back, yours doesn't; it also uses array slices, while yours doesn't. It's clearly a re-write of the OP's code, not yours. You're right about it not sorting properly, though.

Comment: "You're right about it not sorting properly, though." you got that. So according to you and SO, style is more important than *working* code?

Comment: @sebnukem I don't know where you got that idea. I just said that Hynek clearly didn't copy your answer.

Comment: I see somebody downvoted me even I have added the version with fixed algorithm. The see me rolling and they hating. LOL Herd behaviour.

Comment: chill... have a cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the outer loop go from the back to the front of the array? Also the `$k = @array< $i - 1` statement in the for inner loop doesn't make sense.

```
my @array = (5,6,3,1,7,3,2,9,10,4);

my $i, $k;
for ($i = $#array; $i > 0; $i--) { # $#array = last index = length-1
    for ($k = 0; $k < $i; $k++) {
        if ($array[$k] > $array[$k+1]) {
            ($array[$k], $array[$k+1]) = ($array[$k+1], $array[$k]);
        }
    }
}
print "@array\n"; # 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 7 9 10
```

Answer (score -1):

I cannot believe nobody gave him the true PERL answer yet. I believe he asked for it in Perl, not in C transcribed to Perl :)

```
for($i=$#a;$i>0;$i--){$m=$a[0];splice(@a,0,$i+1,map{$s=$m;$m>$_?$_:($s,$m=$_)[0]}@a[1..$i],$m);}
```

Comment: Wiki: Though Perl is not officially an acronym, there are various backronyms in use, the best-known being "Practical Extraction and Reporting Language" ... I'd say both Perl and PERL are fine :D